# can not find the correct source code path when debugging envoy in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, bazel, envoyproxy

I use mac_ci_steps to compile envoy and  use vscode to debug envoy, but the debugger can find the codes in  /var/tmp/_bazel_jiangtao/2dbf1bda33100babc3747f89d5100060/execroot/envoy,
not my source code root.
i want the debugger find the code in /Users/jiangtao/github/envoy
can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: If your're using gdb you should have a look at `substitute-path`